# Python OpenCV Error: -215 : Assertion failed

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect objects using OpenCV and python. This is my code I tried to run.

```
dir_images = r'C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\VOC2007\JPEGImages'
dir_annotations = r'C:\Users\Dell\OneDrive\Desktop\VOC2007\Annotations'
def generate_xml(file):
    labels = np.zeros((20), dtype = 'float32')
    tree = ET.parse(os.path.join(dir_annotations, file + ".xml"))
    raw_image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(dir_images, file + ".jpg"))
    res_img = cv2.resize(raw_image, (224,224))
    for elems in tree.iter():
        if elems.tag == "object":
            name = elems.find("name").text
            labelnr = label_names.transform([name])[0]
            labels[labelnr] = 1
      
    return labels, res_img
```

When I run this code it gives following error.

```
error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:3929: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

I just got this error on my own computer, it works fine through Google Colab. What can I do to solve this matter?

Comment: Try to run `python -m pip install -U opencv2`, and then rerun your script

Comment: Where is `file` defined?

Comment: What is the output of `raw_image`?